# How can i track installs number when I create an ad on facebook for my flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, facebook, ads

I created a flutter app and published into play store, and i promote the app on facebook by paying for ads. the problem is facebook can no track the number of installation so i just make a normal ad. how can i integrate facebook sdk to track this installation from the facebbok ads. please need your help...

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_sdk/flutter_facebook_sdk.dart';

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

    String _deepLinkUrl = 'Unknown';
    FlutterFacebookSdk? facebookDeepLinks;
    Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
        String? deepLinkUrl;
        try {
            facebookDeepLinks = FlutterFacebookSdk();
            facebookDeepLinks!.onDeepLinkReceived!.listen((event) {
                setState(() {
                    _deepLinkUrl = event;
                });
            });
            deepLinkUrl = await facebookDeepLinks!.getDeepLinkUrl;
            setState(() {
                _deepLinkUrl = deepLinkUrl!;
            });
        } on PlatformException {}
        if (!mounted) return;
    }
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initPlatformState();
    }
    Future<void> setAdvertiserTracking() async {
        await facebookDeepLinks!.setAdvertiserTracking(isEnabled: true);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Observer(
            builder: (_) => MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                navigatorObservers: [
                    FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
                ],
                home: SplashScreen(),
                theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
                darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
                themeMode: appStore.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                scrollBehavior: SBehavior(),
                supportedLocales: LanguageDataModel.languageLocales(),
                localizationsDelegates: [AppLocalizations.delegate,         
                GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate, GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate],
                localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) => locale,
                locale: Locale(appStore.selectedLanguage!.languageCode.validate(value:     
                DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)),
            ),
        );
  }
}

`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should integrate the Facebook App Events library in your app:

https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events

Moreover, you can found other useful information on the Facebook documentation page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/measuring/installs-and-in-app-conversions/